# Image component flickering when navigating between pages React Native + Expo

Tags: image, react-native, caching, expo

I'm currently working on an app that has a database that stores the link to the image sources (it's not locally stored) and then in the app, I use that link for the source.
I get a white flickering when navigating and so far, all the solutions I've found are either not compatible with expo (react-native-fast-image) or not compatible with image links (using defaultSource).

Has anyone solved image flickering on Expo with a image not stored locally?

Answer (score 0):

Today, we are pleased to announce that with the arrival of Expo SDK 42, you can now create custom development clients in the cloud using EAS Build, or locally with the new Expo run commands.

You can try it out today:

- Create a new project: expo init
- Install the packages: expo install react-native-fast-image expo-dev-client

Build the native app:

- In the cloud with eas build -p all --profile development (expo build does not support custom builds)
- Or locally with expo run:ios and expo run:android (note: see https://expo.fyi/prebuild-cleanup for information on the generated files)

To be clear, `react-native-fast-image` will not have been added to the Expo Go app that you download from the App Store or Google Play Store.

We still consider this feature to be completed because users can now create a custom client app that includes this library, without needing to write any native code.

We hope you enjoy, and we have big plans to continue improving this workflow going forward!

(с) Brent Vatne https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/react-native-fast-image